# Как зафиксировать фон для div?

Tags: css, html

Есть такая вот верстка лендинга, не резиновая, статичная: http://codepen.io/emelyanova/pen/eNdmrJ

Проблема в том, что при уменьшении размера экрана Фон `div` не фиксируется, появляется область белого цвета.

Я думала это отступы, но не попала. Я игралась с  `background-size` - не помогает.

Прошу, укажите на мою ошибку.

Задача: сделать так, чтобы фоны `div` не двигались от масштабирования окна.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста другой пример или скриншот, так как картинки не подгружаются и не понятно в чем проблема.

Comment: Если реч идет о `header`, то уберите `background-position: 50% 50%;`

Comment: Картинки догрузила.
background-position: 50% 50%; - убрала. Изначально его и не было, не работала все равно. Это я от отчаянья.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы убрать белый отступ, нужно задать минимальную ширину для `body`, тогда при достижение заданного расширения экрана, background перестанет уменьшаться и соответственно белой полосы не будет.

```
body {
    min-width: 940px;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXGwyV)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на повторение фонового изображения, у Вас стоит no-repeat. Проверьте, не мало ли изображение, когда вы применяете масштаб.
Если не хотите повтора фонового изображения, используйте:
background-size:cover или background-size:contain
в зависимости от ситуации

**Понял я почему у Вас так. установите в background-size значение в 100%**

Comment: Изначальный размер 1500 пикс. Более чем достаточно....

Спасибо за ответ. Буду рада дальнейшему общению.

Comment: желательно, чтобы выложили скриншот

Comment: Прошу, уточните, скин чего? ошибки? Исходника?

http://i.imgur.com/rkxgl0s.jpg - исходник.

http://prntscr.com/77btvu - баг...

Comment: сказал же, что изображение маленькое

Comment: ААААААААААААА!!!!!

ДОШЛО!!!!

СПАСИБО! Убежала ковыряться!!!

Comment: Нет. Не помогает....

Comment: http://codepen.io/Vektord/pen/RPGPvb  Я Вас снова не понимаю. Что Вы хотите? Ретину или "убрать эти гадкие белые отступы"?

Comment: ретину - нет. Отступы - да.

Comment: отступы - background-size: 100% auto;

Comment: скорее всего тут проблема не в отступах и не в привязке фона, а в самом подходе к верстке, блин... Я, выходит, хочу сделать РЕЗИНОВЫЙ дизайн. Так что мучения закрываем.

БОЛЬШОЕ ВАМ СПАСИБО!!! Теперь о фонах я знаю много больше!

Comment: раз у Вас статичная верстка, то проблем то и быть не должно) пишите,  буду рад помочь